# Does exchanging SDP insecurely jeopardize the security of a peer connection?

Tags: webrtc

When developing a WebRTC connection, would using an insecure signaling channel (like WebSockets over the `ws:` protocol as opposed to `wss:`) used for exchange of the ICE candidates jeopardize the security of the subsequently established peer connection?

My intuition says no, because ICE candidates only tell you how to connect to a peer and the offer and answer SDP strings contain a `fingerprint` line as well as the `ufrag` credential which while they can be intercepted would only be useful to an attacker willing to join the session as a third peer thus revealing their presence, right?

Would knowledge of the SDP allow an attacker to decypher the data channel messages / stream samples without announcing themselves as a part of the connection?

Aside from the security of the signaling channel, once ICE connection is established, does the security of the actual page running the WebRTC code matter? By security I mostly mean HTTP(S) here, but I also generally care about of what it would take to break the connection in order to be able to listen in on it.

Comment: Yes. You're vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: @jib I found this https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-and-man-in-the-middle-attacks/ which explains things quite nicely thanks to you prompting me to search for "webrtc mitm" and not the contrieved queries I did prior struggling to find the best way to search for this, failing to realize this is still a simple MITM because we are attacking the signaling channel not the SRTP.  This question then turns out to be a dupe of not one but several. Thanks!